# Mongo - manually (re)set padding factor

Tags: mongodb

I had a pile of data that I needed to seed into a mongo collection.  At a high level, the goal was to bin each element into a parent document, and periodically update the db (It was a long running process and I wanted to create save points in case the script err'd out).  Here's the pseudo code:

```
for element in dataset :
    {
        "akey" : adoc
        ...
    }[element["key"]]["elements"].append(element)

    if(periodically())
        print(status())
        db.sums.update({"name":"akey"},adoc)
        ...
```

When I run db.sums.stats() my paddingFactor is close to 4.0 because mongo thinks my documents have a habit of growing.  This is unfortunate, since I will only be adding large, but static documents from here on out.  I could run compact now, but that won't change the collection's padding factor.  And I could wait for the padding factor to converge back down to 1, but I'll have to remember to run compact later.  So is there any way I can (re)set the padding factor now?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an optional `paddingFactor` to use with [`compact()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/) in MongoDB 2.2+:

> **paddingFactor**: Optional. Applicable for the MMAPv1 storage engine only. Specifies the padding to use (as a factor of the document size) during the compact operation. The paddingFactor does not affect the padding of subsequent record allocations after compact completes.

Comment: I addressed that in my question - I'm asking for how to change the paddingFactor of subsequent record allocations.

Comment: @xavier You suggested that paddingFactor wouldn't change with compact() (it does). However, if you're looking to set the paddingFactor explicitly there isn't a method for that. Don't think that merits a downvote ;-)

Comment: But that's the title of my question.  If you edit your answer to state it's impossible (and perhaps describe why, from a design perspective), I'll un-downvote you.